# Ошибка в logwatch

Tags: linux, сервер

Установил на сервер logwatch 7.4.2 через скрипт инсталл внутри пакета, но получил проблему, а именно при вводе:

```
sudo logwatch --mailto МЭЙЛ
```

получаю такой вывод:

```
/config/scripts/shared/, No such file or directory
```

Что не так? Полагаю какие то пути не прописаны как надо.

Comment: наверно, всё-таки лучше ставить пакет из репозитория вашего дистрибутива.

Comment: да, но там старая версия

Comment: Какой дистрибутив?

Comment: Есть какие-то киллер фичи у новой версии, что нельзя использовать старую?

Comment: linux ubuntu 14.04